# Arduino IDE COM Port error on Windows 10

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-micro

I have an Arduino micro, uno, and mega and none of them will connect to the com port on the Arduino IDE. I went to the device manager aand it is recognized but when I try to update the driver I get this:
[image]

Any help of how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

An easy thing to try but might not help: Use another USB port of your computer and see if the driver is reinstalled.

Otherwise, go to control panel and find the drivers (Device Manager), search for the Ports (COM & LPT) drivers and remove the driver for the Arduino manually, reconnect the Arduino and check if it is installed correctly. Possibly a wrong version of an Arduino driver is installed. If another driver is installed at COM3 (where is my Arduino), remove that driver and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Try to update or reinstall com port driver in control panel/device manager...

Option 2: There might be problem while installing Arduino IDE or problem occur during Arduino gets board and library updates over air itself. Try to reinstall IDE.